# Why is Eclipse not able to resolve Guice import in Play 2.2.x application?

Tags: sbt, guice, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to use Google Guice Injections in my Play 2.2.2 project. My `build.sbt` file contains this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.0-beta",
  "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
)
```

When running `play dependencies`, I can see that the guice dependency is being resolved correctly. However, when trying to make the `import com.google.inject.*` statement it seems that the library is not available:

[image]

I don't have this problem with any other imported dependencies, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Execute `eclipse` task and refresh the project in Eclipse.

As a quick check of the import being really in the dependency, execute `play console` and type in `import com.google.inject.*`. If `sbt console` can resolve the import, it's an issue with Eclipse that didn't seem to refresh the project.

Don't forget to `reload` an active session of `play` after every change to the build.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on console in your project directory -

your project dir $:> **play compile eclipse**

and then refresh your project on eclipse.

Play doesn't have any plugin on eclipse but play provide the utility to import your project into eclipse. so whenever you add a new dependency you should compile and eclipsify your project otherwise eclipse will not understand the new dependency imports.