# Where does "play dependencies" come from?

Tags: playframework-2.3

In another question [Why is Eclipse not able to resolve Guice import in Play 2.2.x application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26529648/1305344) I learnt about `play dependencies` command.

```
[play-new-app] $ dependencies
[info] :: delivering :: play-new-app#play-new-app_2.11;1.0-SNAPSHOT :: 1.0-SNAPSHOT :: integration :: Thu Oct 23 23:56:30 CEST 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/play-new-app/target/scala-2.11/ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml

Here are the resolved dependencies of your application:

+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Module                                                     | Required by                                                | Note                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| com.typesafe.play:play-ws_2.11:2.3.5                       | play-new-app:play-new-app_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT                | As play-ws_2.11-2.3.5.jar                  |
...
```

I can't seem to inspect it by a means of `help` or `inspect` in sbt/activator session.

```
[play-new-app] $ inspect dependencies
[error] Not a valid project ID: dependencies
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: dependencies (similar: ivy-dependencies, all-dependencies, rpm-dependencies)
[error] inspect dependencies
[error]                     ^
```

Where does the command come from? Is this supported (since the last trace of the command is in [Play 1.2.1's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.1/dependency))? Where could I find a page about the command in the docs for the latest release, 2.3.5?

Comment: in 2.3.5 I do see dependencyGraph and whatDependsOn which may help provide similar information but I can't answer main question.

Answer (score 0):

`dependencies` is a command as are `h2-browser`, `license`, and `classpath`. They're all defined in [PlayCommands](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala) with [dependencies](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala#L367) and available to any Play project through the Play plugin.

It appears that `inspect` and `help` don't work with commands in sbt.

Comment: so to use in my project ...what would I need to do? started up activator and typed dependencies get  not a valid command

Comment: How did you create the project? What template did you choose? `play-scala`? What does `project/plugins.sbt` hold?